# What are the requirements for an ALE employer notifying employees about open enrollment under the Affordable Care Act?

Tags: united-states, employer

My understanding is that employers can choose when to offer open enrollment and for how long. However, my question is whether an employer is required to notify their employees about their open enrollment period, and what are the requirements for doing so. For example, if my company only posts this information on their Facebook page, or some similar method that requires the employees to go look for it (without knowing when it will be posted), is that allowed?

If it makes a difference, my employer is an Applicable Large Employer under the ACA.

I've tried to find this information from several sources, but everything I find is merely a recommendation on how or when to provide this information. One source stated that it was the employer's responsibility to notify employees, but did not define what (if anything) notifying legally entailed or offer any legal source at all for this information.